# How to Automate a specific range in an Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pretty new to Apps Script..
I have written an Apps script for a v lookup and import range and every week I have to update the Spreadsheet URL once the original spreadsheet is generated and then I have to copy and paste that URL into my Apps script to reflect it into the tabs in the spreadsheet. I have 6 Tabs and so I have to copy and paste the URL numerous number of times in each of the script.

Is there a script or a code that I can write so that I only have to Copy and paste the URL for the spreadsheet once.?

This is what I have done..

```
function Week14() {
  //Karen
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Karen Z1"); 
  
  sheet1.getRange("P36:P45").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),3,false)')
   sheet1.getRange("P50:P59").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),5,false)')
    sheet1.getRange("P64:P73").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),6,false)')
     sheet1.getRange("P78:P87").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),8,false)')
      sheet1.getRange("P120:P129").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),9,false)')

//Muhamed  
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Muhamed Z2"); 
 

  sheet1.getRange("P30:P36").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),3,false)')
   sheet1.getRange("P41:P47").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),5,false)')
    sheet1.getRange("P52:P58").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),6,false)')
     sheet1.getRange("P63:P69").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),8,false)')
      sheet1.getRange("P96:P102").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),9,false)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn JavaScript basic concepts like variables and string concatenation.

---

```
var url = 'put here your spreadsheet url';
```

then instead of

```
sheet1.getRange("P36:P45").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("**URL**","SA & NT!E:T"),3,false)')
```

you could use

```
sheet1.getRange("P36:P45").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("' + url + '","SA & NT!E:T"),3,false)')
```

Do the same for the other statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help..I have put in the code that you suggested however it comes up with Syntax error..'
function Week14() {
  //Karen
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Karen Z1"); 
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rOyKt3cfk2SlJzTS1JeUrbh4lfUHZbuCdT5cVZdXhmc/edit#gid=7205478';
  
  sheet1.getRange("P36:P45").setFormulaR1C1('=vlookup(R[0]C1,importrange("'+ url'","SA & NT!E:T"),3,false)')'

Comment: @Sajal I'm sorry, there was missing a `+` after `url`.